# Animate opacity not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a little jQuery dropdown menu that worked when I used [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) just fine, so the selectors and the HTML are fine.

However, the `fadeIn` gives some ugly behavior in IE.  I changed the menu to animate the opacity instead of the `fadeIn` using template code I found here. The only problem is it's not working; Any hints?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#nav li").hover(
        function () {
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"opacity": 1});
        },function(){
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"opacity": 0});
    });//hover

});// document ready
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="arav" /><ul id="nav"> 
<li> <a href="index2.html">Home</a> 
</li> 
<li> <a href="personnel.html">Who We Are</a> 
</li> 
<li> <a href="#">Facts</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="sci.html">Sci</a></li> 
<li><a href="tbi.html">Tbi</a></li> 
<li><a href="stroke.html">Str</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 
<li> <a href="">Education</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="healthed.html">Health Education</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">KARRN Materials</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="handouts.html">Handouts</a></li> 
<li><a href="presentations.html">Presentations</a></li> 
<li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 

<li><a href="sciinfosheets.html">SCI Info Sheets</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 
<li> <a href="stroke.html">Resources</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="statelevel.html">State Level</a></li> 
<li><a href="nationallevel.html">National Level</a></li> 
<li><a href="resourcesbycoutny2.html">Community Level</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 

<li> <a href="research.html">Research</a></li> 

<li> <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You will still get the ugly look in IE just fyi.

Comment: well, with the fadeIn the submenu just appears and there's no gradually fading.  I know you can add a z-index to the menu and it will fadeIn but I think the clear type font messes with that.  I've seen animate opacity work in IE once or twice.

Answer (score 2):

If Turshar's example does not work, try using `fadeTo`, I think that works around the IE opacity issue.

```
$(this).children("ul").fadeTo(500, 1);
```

and

```
$(this).children("ul").fadeTo(500, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know that `$("#nav li")` targets **every** `<li>` under `<ul id="nav">`, thus includes all submenus?

What you probably want to do is: `$("#nav > li")`.
Using `>` in CSS you can tell it that you only want the direct child (thus not children of children etc).

Look here for the documentation and an example: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/. But you can also search for "CSS selectors" for more information on selecting elements in the document.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

`opacity` does not work with IE, you need to change to `filter` property

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#nav li").hover(
        function () {
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"opacity": 1});
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"filter":"alpha(opacity=50)"});
        },function(){
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"opacity": 0});
        $(this).children("ul").animate({"filter":"alpha(opacity=0)"});
    });//hover

});
```

Comment: the code posted isn't working in chrome either.  no menu appears, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Tushar: Please consider caching your selectors. You're building a jQuery object of `this` (`$(this)`, and then building another jQuery object of it's `ul` children (`.children('ul')`) multiple times. `var children = $(this).children('ul'); children.animate({"opacity": 1}); children.animate({"filter":"alpha(opacity=50)"});` Or even better, combine your `animate` calls into a single one.

Comment: Beware, setting `filter` manually is a bad idea. jQuery already sets the `filter`-property whenever you use `opacity` to reduce cross-browser differences. Therefore the animations may even interfere in some cases. Basically, when you're using jQuery, *never* set filter-property.